# How to write code for Next and Previous Buttons in Media controler in android

Tags: android

Hello Friends i am using Media controler in my code and i am including below code but can any body tell me what should i write inside this methods so i can play next and previous songs in media player .

```
        mediaController.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                //next button clicked

                  myVideoView.setVideoPath(filename);
              }
            }, new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                //previous button clicked
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have an array list like this..

```
 ArrayList<String> filename = new ArrayList<String>();
```

with all the files you want to play..

maintain an index of currently being played filename... and you can move to next and previous filenames using that index..

Comment: Hello Raju Thanx do u have any code or sample project of Media controller ?

Comment: No..:(.. but the answer i gave is very easy to implement.... from where are you playing your files?.. i mean where are the files stored?

Comment: see files are inside my sd card ,i am able to access and able to show on listview now playing this from another activity so the problem is from another activity how to increase list eleement .

Comment: If it is another activity... make the array list static... the you can use.. youuractivityname.yourlist.add(//);.. this from other activities also...